# What's the best way to allow a user to select from multiple functions to run in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

I've got 20 files, each defining their own function. Sets of files are related. Each file defines a sport and an age group. So, as an example, these functions exist, each in their own individual file:

```
footballAdults()
footballTeens()
footballKids()
tennisAdults()
tennisTeens()
```

.... etc.

I want to allow the user to to call any one of them through a main file, filtering their choices like so:

```
x = input("Pick a sport:")
y = input ("Pick an age group:")
```

Then, the program will filter through the user's choices to run the function the user has chosen.

Is there a better way to do this other than by doing a huge if...elif...elif...elif...else statement, or am I stuck doing that?

Example:

```
from footballAdults import footballAdults
from footballTeens import footballTeens
from footballKids import footballKids
from tennisAdults import tennisAdults
#this would continue on until all 20 files have had their functions imported

x = input("Pick a sport:")
y = input ("Pick an age group:")

if x == ("football") and y == ("adults")
    footballAdults()
elif x == ("football") and y == ("teens")
    footballTeens()
elif x == ("football") and y == ("kids")
    footballKids()
elif x == ("tennis") and y == ("adults")
    tennisAdults()
#this would continue on until the final else statement
#cycling through all 20 functions
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a dictionary dispatcher:

```
from footballAdults import footballAdults
from footballTeens import footballTeens
from footballKids import footballKids
from tennisAdults import tennisAdults

x = input("Pick a sport:")
y = input ("Pick an age group:")

d = {('football', 'adults'): footballAdults,
     ('football', 'teens'): footballTeens,
     ('football', 'kids'): footballKids,
     ('tennis', 'adults'): tennisAdults}

d[(x, y)]()
```

**Explanation**

- Store your tuple keys (matching values of `x` and `y`) together with function values in a dictionary.
- Call your function via the dictionary.

Comment: I've tried implementing this but it seems to run each of the functions in some way beforehand. Each of the functions (e.g. footballAdults) creates a file specific to that function to write data. However, using this dictionary approach leads to every single file being opened as the import statements are run though I imagine. Perhaps it's a problem with the individual functions in this case?

Comment: Yes, it seems like your functions are incorrectly defined.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks!